# Printing issue in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I built a report in Access that is too wide for the standard copy paper (even after adjusting the margins to 0'. and reformatting the actual report itself). Basically, I am looking for a "shrink to fit" option, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Is there a way to make my report fit onto one page without exporting the document to another format? Or will I actually have to purchase some bigger paper?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's just a little too wide, even with the margins zeroed out. Is there a way to shrink the fields down automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an option does not exist. Butwhat about printing to PDF ? I think Acrobat has an option to automatically rotate and adjust to your paper.

Comment: I tried this, but since the pages are cut off in the report, when you PDF them, they are still cut off, only now they are in PDF format.

Comment: But if you change the *paper* setup in the orininal report, they shouldn't be cutoff !?

Answer (score 0):

Does the option exist to reduce the size of all the elements so that the report does fit on one page normally?  I mean, reduce the font size, reduce the field sizes; but not to the point that either the text is unreadable - or the fields start cutting your output off?

Sometimes the best way is to format the report around the idea that you will need to print it off on a normal sheet of paper first, then expand it from there if you find you have too much white space.

Just my $0.02 though, your mileage may vary.